# Hibernate Annotations (Spring), setting default value when adding new boolean column, getting error?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring, jpa

I am trying to add a new column to an existing database table. It is for a boolean and I am trying like below but getting the error:

> Can not set boolean field
>   org.jadefalcon.demo.domain.Users.permissionconceptsearchtab
>   to null value

what I am trying (I found info on this from searching but it seems I am doing it wrong)

```
@Column(name = "permissionconceptsearchtab",nullable=false,
columnDefinition="boolean default false")
private boolean permissionconceptsearchtab;
```

I'd like to avoid having to drop the table and reload the data so am wondering what I need to do so it will make any existing rows as false when adding this new column. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what this has to do with Hibernate - are you using a tool like hbm2ddl to auto-generate the SQL statements to create the table?

Simply add the column onto the table with an `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN ...` statement, setting a `DEFAULT false` value in your SQL.

The exception you get from Hibernate is because a primitive type, like `boolean` can never be `null`, only `true` or `false`. A `Boolean`, however, can either be `null`, `Boolean.TRUE`, or `Boolean.FALSE`.